# Can't find the definition of a typedef

Tags: c, typedef

I have my `file.h`:

```
#ifnotdef _FILE_H_
#define _FILE_H_
#include "lista2.h"
    struct texto{
        int col_cursor;
        int lin_cursor;
        lista2* texto;
        int tecla;
    };
    typedef struct texto Texto;  
#endif //_FILE_H_
```

And I have my `file.c`

```
#include "file.h"
#include "lista2.h"   

     void recua_linha(Texto* t){
           if(!(t->texto->corrente == t->texto->primeiro))
             t->lin_cursor--;
    }
```

`lista2.h`

```
#ifndef _LISTA2_H_
#define _LISTA2_H_
    typedef struct lista2 lista2;
    typedef struct elemento elemento;
#endif //_LISTA2_H_
```

`lista2.c`

```
#include "lista2.h"
    struct elemento{
        dado_t str;
        elemento* ant;
        elemento* prox;
    };

struct lista2{
    elemento* primeiro;
    elemento* ultimo;
    elemento* corrente;
};
```

But when I try to access any member of `Texto` I get

```
Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I know it means that: *The Program knows the Type but cant see it's implementation.* I just can't know why or how to solve it.

Ps: I also need to access `Texto`.members in `main.c` file.

Comment: You forgot to `#include "file.h"` in your `file.c`?

Comment: I'd like to know why the Close vote ? I DID NOT FORGOT TO ADD FILE.H omg

Comment: So based on Obs2, the error is related to the other struct.

Comment: Having a field `texto` inside a `struct texto` that then is `typedef`ed to `texto` is a bit confusing, don't you think? Especially if the type of that field is not defined.

Comment: The incomplete type is `lista2`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Is there a way to fix it and allow me to see both headers in both files (header and main). ?

Comment: Please, look into the help text and learn how to ask questions properly.

Comment: So here it is. The `file.c` doesn't know anything about the fields of `lista2`, since they are visible only in `lista2.c`. `lista2.h` is exporting only the opaque type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So it's not possible to do what I want ? let both files (`main.c` and `texto.c`) see the implementation of `texto.h` plus `texto.c` see `lista.c` implementation ?

Comment: does `#ifnotdef _FILE_H_` really work? I only know `#ifndef _FILE_H_` or `#if !defined(_FILE_H_)`

Comment: You seem to want conflicting things.  By putting the definition of `struct lista2` in file `lista2.c` instead of in `lista2.h`, you appear to want to *hide* the details of its implementation.  In `file.c`, on the other hand, you want to know the details.  There are various ways to approach this, but first you have to settle on what exactly it is that you want.

Comment: here is the pure and simple: 1) do not typedef a struct.  that just clutters the code, leads to misunderstandings, problems like your having, and clutters the compiler name space.  2) a struct, defined in one .c file is not available in another .c file.  Rather place the struct definition in the .h file.  This goes for both the struct definitions in the lista2.c file.  Move those struct definitions to the appropriate .h file  Then include that .h file wherever an instance of the struct is needed to be declared.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I explained in my answer why this failed and how to fix it, didn't it help?

Answer (score 1):

Take this piece of code from file.c:

```
t->texto->corrente
```

with `t` being a `Texto` struct. Now, from file.h, we have that this:

```
lista2* texto;
```

is a member of `Texto` struct. Now we have to look at what file.c knows about `lista2`. We have to look at the headers included in file.c, i.e. file.h and lista2.h. The first doesn't have anything relevant. The second however, does have this: `typedef struct lista2 lista2;`, which helps. *But*, you are requesting a data member named `corrente`, but lista2.h does not provide any info about the data members of `lista2`, thus you should receive an error similar to this:

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

because all file.c knows is the `typedef` it sees in lista2.h.

---

In order to do what you want, you should modify your lista2.h like this:

```
#ifndef _LISTA2_H_
#define _LISTA2_H_
// moved it here, in order to use just 'elemento'
typedef struct elemento elemento;
struct elemento {
  // I do not know what dato_t is...discarded
  elemento* ant;
  elemento* prox;
};

struct lista2 {
  elemento* primeiro;
  elemento* ultimo;
  elemento* corrente;
};

typedef struct lista2 lista2;
#endif //_LISTA2_H_
```

leaving lista2.c empty. Also notice that I do not see why to add a tab before the stucts (the indentation starts from the first column of the file), so I removed it.

By the way, in file.h, maybe you would like to change this

```
#ifnotdef _FILE_H_
```

to this

```
#ifndef _FILE_H_
```

since you should receive this

> Invalid preprocessor directive: ifnotdef

Notice that in order to access `Texto` from `main()`, you should include file.h in the main file.

---

*Tip*: A very good habit is to use a language that the community can (fully) understand in your code (English!) and you probably, if you need to develop code in the future for real world applications, usage of English is a must.